# Declaratively create logic in your org that prevents two Opportunities from being created on a single Account in a single day

Tags: workflow, formula, validation, learning

Found this question on sfdc99.com as an example of possible Salesforce developer interview questions. Does anyone know how this can be done? Of course, **without** coding.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a text field on Opportunity that is marked as "unique" and doesn't allow duplicate values. Then use a Workflow Rule and Field Update to update the field with the account/date combination eg:

```
AccountId & "-" & YEAR(CreatedDate) & "-" & MONTH(CreatedDate) & "-" & DAY(CreatedDate)
```

The workflow criteria would be `true` so that it fired all the time.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to rollup the max opportunity date to the account, then have a validation rule check if the newly created opportunity date is equal to the custom rollup field on the account.